# htaccess redirect with exceptions

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, exception

I work on a Wordpress Network. Let's say that the main site has the link *www.main-site-**old**.com*, and all the other sites in this network have links like *www.main-site-**old**.com/site1* , *www.main-site-**old**.com/site2* e.t.c.

I want to redirect ONLY the main site to a new domain (let's say *www.main-site-**new**.com*) and let all the others stay as they are.

I tried this one:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.main-site-new.com/
```

but it redirects the whole domain (for example it redirects *www.main-site-**old**.com/site1* to *www.main-site-**new**.com/site1*)

I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/site1
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://main-site-new.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With  `mod_alias` `redirect` you will not be able to use `regex` to capture a request for `http://www.main-site-old.com` only so, you could use another one `RedirectMatch`  like this :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ http://www.main-site-new.com
```

Or  go to `mod_rewrite` by this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$   http://www.main-site-new.com [R=301,L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test.